# Postfix check how many emails a user is trying to send before queuing them

Tags: mysql, php, postfix, ubuntu-18.04

I have `Postfix` installed, and set as a send-only `smtp` server, on a VPS(running ubuntu 18.04).

Now I want to limit a user to 100 emails/day(if possible saving that limit - sent and remaining - inside a mysql database).

How do i do that?

I can go trough the logs using php and saving how many have been sent but that's only after the emails have been sent. What if a user is queuing up 500 emails and i can't check how many he's trying to send until after those emails are queued?

Is it possible to somehow check how many emails are about to be sent before? Is it possible to cut connection with a warning when the daily limit is reached?

P.S: I would like to use PHP to check all that - if possible of course.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at https://wiki.policyd.org/? It looks like it stores its counters in a mysql database.

Comment: @MarkWagner i think that that's file based and it is not dynamic enough, it uses 1file/user as far as i can tell after reading their docs for the past 2 days :(